# Spring profile with Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

How to set spring.active.profiles when launching task (from shell or dashboard)?

I always have "No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default". This is because I don't know how to set VM arguments like -Dspring.active.profiles=xxx
I use localserver implementation. I use 1.3.0 SPCF version

Thank you

Comment: I tried something like this with no success : task launch --name myjob --arguments "spring.active.profiles=dev"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Spring Cloud Flow Dashboard to activate Spring profiles, then simply add `--spring.profiles.active=dev` in the **Arguments** section while playing the task.

Cheers! 
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

task launch --name myjob --properties "deployer.task1.local.javaOpts=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"